# Katalon in Docker Test Suite Pathing

Tags: powershell, docker, katalon-studio

I have a powershell script which executes the following but struggling to find the Test Suite pathing

```
docker run -t -v ${pwd}:/katalon/katalon/source katalonstudio/katalon katalon-execute.sh -browserType="Chrome" --privileged -retry=0 -statusDelay=15 -testSuiteCollectionPath='/katalon/katalon/source/Test Suites/'
```

I have also tried to reference the Test Suite explicitly (like the official [docs](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/console-mode-execution.html#command-builder))

```
docker run -t -v $(pwd):/katalon/katalon/source katalonstudio/katalon katalon-execute.sh -browserType="Chrome" -retry=0 -statusDelay=15 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/Fund Fact Details"
```

Gives this error:

[image: still gives this error]

If I go into the container and cd to the Test Suite directory I can see the files(as seen below) but the arguments are failing when being passed in via the powershell script

Test suite directory inside container

[image: test suite directory inside container]

Any pathing tips or tricks to try for Bash/Powershell will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which KS version are you using? It might not work in [5.8.2](https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/comment/25024/#Comment_25024).

Comment: Thanks - the latest on docker hub is 5.8.5, so I believe that part should be ok

Answer (score 3):

After much frustration - turns out the shell scripts and bat files were using the wrong Project file in the bin folder. Once I deleted the bin folder it used the correct project in the root Katalon folder and Test Suite pathings were found :)

Comment: The working bat file:

`@echo on

docker run -t --rm -v "%cd%:/tmp/source" -w /tmp/source katalonstudio/katalon katalon-execute.sh -browserType="Chrome" -retry=0 -statusDelay=15 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/Fund Fact Details"

pause`